# How to send current URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, url

I have a contact form. JavaScript with Ajax calls another contact-form.php file. Is there any way to send, with this JavaScript function, the current URL to the PHP file?

I want to see from which page my clients have contacted with me.

In contact-form.php:

```
$message .= "\n\Url: http://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

this is not working.

My contact.js:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var contact = {
        message: null,
        init: function () {
            $('#contact-form input.contact, #contact-form a.contact').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // load the contact form using ajax
                $.get("data/contact.php", function(data){
                    // create a modal dialog with the data
                    $(data).modal({
                        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Iki' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                        position: ["15%",],
                        overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                        containerId: 'contact-container',
                        onOpen: contact.open,
                        onShow: contact.show,
                        onClose: contact.close
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        open: function (dialog) {
            // add padding to the buttons in firefox/mozilla
            if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                $('#contact-container .contact-button').css({
                    'padding-bottom': '2px'
                });
            }
            // input field font size
            if ($.browser.safari) {
                $('#contact-container .contact-input').css({
                    'font-size': '.9em'
                });
            }

            // dynamically determine height
            var h = 280;
            if ($('#contact-subject').length) {
                h += 26;
            }
            if ($('#contact-cc').length) {
                h += 22;
            }

            var title = $('#contact-container .contact-title').html();
            $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Palaukite...');
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn(200, function () {
                dialog.container.fadeIn(200, function () {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn(200, function () {
                        $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                            height: h
                        }, function () {
                            $('#contact-container .contact-title').html(title);
                            $('#contact-container form').fadeIn(200, function () {
                                $('#contact-container #contact-name').focus();

                                $('#contact-container .contact-cc').click(function () {
                                    var cc = $('#contact-container #contact-cc');
                                    cc.is(':checked') ? cc.attr('checked', '') : cc.attr('checked', 'checked');
                                });

                                // fix png's for IE 6
                                if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
                                    $('#contact-container .contact-button').each(function () {
                                        if ($(this).css('backgroundImage').match(/^url[("']+(.*\.png)[)"']+$/i)) {
                                            var src = RegExp.$1;
                                            $(this).css({
                                                backgroundImage: 'none',
                                                filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="' +  src + '", sizingMethod="crop")'
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        show: function (dialog) {
            $('#contact-container .contact-send').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // validate form
                if (contact.validate()) {
                    var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message');
                    msg.fadeOut(function () {
                        msg.removeClass('contact-error').empty();
                    });
                    $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Vygdoma');
                    $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);
                    $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                        height: '80px'
                    }, function () {
                        $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeIn(200, function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'data/contact.php',
                                data: $('#contact-container form').serialize() + '&action=send',
                                type: 'post',
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: 'html',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeOut(200, function () {
                                        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Pavyko!');
                                        msg.html(data).fadeIn(200);
                                    });
                                },
                                error: contact.error
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
                else {
                    if ($('#contact-container .contact-message:visible').length > 0) {
                        var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message div');
                        msg.fadeOut(200, function () {
                            msg.empty();
                            contact.showError();
                            msg.fadeIn(200);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#contact-container .contact-message').animate({
                            height: '30px'
                        }, contact.showError);
                    }

                }
            });
        },
        close: function (dialog) {
            $('#contact-container .contact-message').fadeOut();
            $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Iki greito :)');
            $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);
            $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                height: 40
            }, function () {
                dialog.data.fadeOut(200, function () {
                    dialog.container.fadeOut(200, function () {
                        dialog.overlay.fadeOut(200, function () {
                            $.modal.close();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        },
        validate: function () {
            contact.message = '';
            if (!$('#contact-container #contact-name').val()) {
                contact.message += 'Įveskite vardą';
            }

            var email = $('#contact-container #contact-email').val();
            if (!email) {
                contact.message += ' įveskite E-Paštą';
            }
            else {
                if (!contact.validateEmail(email)) {
                    contact.message += 'Klaidingas E-Paštas. ';
                }
            }
            if (!$('#contact-container #contact-subject').val()) {
                contact.message += 'Įveskite nuorodą';
            }

            if (!$('#contact-container #contact-message').val()) {
                contact.message += 'Komentaras yra būtinas.';
            }

            if (contact.message.length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        validateEmail: function (email) {
            var at = email.lastIndexOf("@");

            // Make sure the at (@) sybmol exists and  
            // it is not the first or last character
            if (at < 1 || (at + 1) === email.length)
                return false;

            // Make sure there aren't multiple periods together
            if (/(\.{2,})/.test(email))
                return false;

            // Break up the local and domain portions
            var local = email.substring(0, at);
            var domain = email.substring(at + 1);

            // Check lengths
            if (local.length < 1 || local.length > 64 || domain.length < 4 || domain.length > 255)
                return false;

            // Make sure local and domain don't start with or end with a period
            if (/(^\.|\.$)/.test(local) || /(^\.|\.$)/.test(domain))
                return false;

            // Check for quoted-string addresses
            // Since almost anything is allowed in a quoted-string address,
            // we're just going to let them go through
            if (!/^"(.+)"$/.test(local)) {
                // It's a dot-string address...check for valid characters
                if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%*\/?|^{}`~&'+=_\.]*$/.test(local))
                    return false;
            }

            // Make sure domain contains only valid characters and at least one period
            if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/.test(domain) || domain.indexOf(".") === -1)
                return false;   

            return true;
        },
        showError: function () {
            $('#contact-container .contact-message')
                .html($('<div class="contact-error"></div>').append(contact.message))
                .fadeIn(200);
        }
    };

    contact.init();
});
```

Comment: where are you sending the url in your code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send it, if you're looking to have access to the name of the file the AJAX call was sent **from** in the php file that receives the request, you can use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Which is useful if you're going to be receiving requests to that file from multiple locations.

Answer (score 4):

```
- alert(document.URL)

- alert(Window.location.href)

- alert(document.location.href)

- alert(window.location.pathname)
```

Try any of these,it will give yout he current url.

Comment: thanks for fast reply, can you say where exactly I should put it in code and how to call it then in contact-form.php?

Comment: put it anywhere in the code...that does not matter!!!i am not sure about what you are saying...call it then in contact-form.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current url in js with `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can get the url of the current page by using the `window` object. `window.location.href` will typically get you what you want, barring the case of frames within a page.

You can simply add this as a paramter to your ajax call, regardless of the page you're sending it to, or your back-end implementation.

Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/86fjT/).

```
$(function () {
    var postParams = {
        "myUrl": window.location.href
    };
    $.post("/echo/json/", {
        "json": JSON.stringify(postParams)
    }, function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```